# How to check user have permission or not on url in django

Tags: django, django-permissions

How to check user have permission or not  on URL in Django

I have URL -  admin/users/userprofile

and I want to check that login user have permission to access how to do that ?

```
def get_nav_list(context, **kwargs): 
    request = context['request']
    navigation = Navigation.objects.all()
    menus = []
    menu_tree = {}
    for nav in navigation:

        if nav.parent_id is None:
            menus.append(nav.navigation_weight)
            menu_tree[nav.id] = {}
            menu_tree[nav.id]['parent'] = nav
            menu_tree[nav.id]['children'] = {}

    for nav in navigation:
        if nav.parent_id:
            if  check_menu_permissions(nav.navigation_link , request.user):
                menu_tree[nav.parent_id]['children'][nav.id] = nav
```

Question about `check_menu_permissions`  function

```
Note: I have build navigation Module like wordpress in django
```

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: Question updated